# Python - add channel for conda kafka install

Tags: python, apache-kafka, anaconda

I'm attempting to create a conda environment based on requirements.txt:

Running command:

```
conda create --name kafka-consumer --file requirements.txt
```

returns error:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - confluent-kafka[version='>=1.4.2']
```

requirements.txt from https://github.com/confluentinc/examples/blob/latest/clients/cloud/python/requirements.txt

contains:

```
requests
certifi
confluent-kafka[avro,json,protobuf]>=1.4.2
```

How to discover which channel I need to add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-confluent-kafka/ use one of:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-confluent-kafka
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 python-confluent-kafka
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 python-confluent-kafka
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 python-confluent-kafka
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on OS that you have
I don't think Anaconda on WIN owners able to install confluent-kafka related packages
(till this date)
but I suggest to install it via CDM and run your code without Anaconda on any IDE